# Prestashop Webservice: Multiple cart Rows

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am working with prestashop 1.6 and have a fully working setup with the webservice(api) and prest5ashop but I have a slightly issue with the cart adding mechanism.

Basically I go to create my cart but when I do each subsequent item I add (cart_row) under (cart_rows) seems to be malformed and thus does not get added.

My code is:

```
$product_list = array(
"1" => array("id_product" => "219", "quantity" => "1"),
"2" => array("id_product" => "219", "quantity" => "1"),
"3" => array("id_product" => "219", "quantity" => "3")   
);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($product_list as $product) {
                $xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[$i]->id_product = $product['id_product'];
                $xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[$i]->quantity = $product['quantity'];
                $i++;
            }

$opt = array('resource' => 'carts');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($opt); echo '</pre>';
$xml = $webService->add($opt);
$id['cart'] = $xml->cart->id; // ID of created cart
```

So basically in the above example, product 1 gets added but 2 and 3 do not.  When I look at the XML response from Prestashop I notice this:

```
<associations>
<cart_rows>
        <cart_row>
        <id_product>219</id_product>
        <id_product_attribute/>
        <id_address_delivery/>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        </cart_row>
<cart_row><id_product>219</id_product><quantity>1</quantity></cart_row><cart_row><id_product>219</id_product><quantity>3</quantity></cart_row></cart_rows>
</associations>
```

I can see the second and third products added seem malformed, but I do not understand why.  Can anybody help out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why id product are same? Same id product with different quantity will not be accepted in multiple cart rows. It should be added before sending. Please use there different id product and share the result.

Comment: This was exactly the issue, thank you very much.  Even though the Web Service did not return a valid error the issue was repeat product IDs.  The prestashop webservice will not add the product if the IDs repeat or are not valid, it will not give this back as an error even with debug enabled.